# How to FTP multiple folders to another server using mput in Unix?

Tags: unix, ftp

I am logged in on a server (using Putty). from there I'm connecting using FTP to another server. I want to copy several folders from the first server to the second server using mput.

Like:

```
ftp> mput folder1 folder2 folder3
```

But I get "folder1: not a plain file."...and so on. Each of these folders have subfolders, files (some binary, some not).

How can I accomplish what I want without zipping the stuff and then transfer?

Answer (score 22):

Command line FTP is pretty primitive.

You can't recursively send files/folders towards a remote site.

If you want to recreate a directory structure on the remote side the same as the local, you need to manually `mkdir` each path and use `mput *` to send everything in that directory to the remote side.

Two options to make this easier:

1. Stop using the primitive FTP command (ncftp is a good alternative)
2. Use tar to tar up the folders, send the file and extract on the far side.

Comment: +1 for tar->put->untar

Comment: -1 Because question asks "How can I accomplish what I want without zipping the stuff and then transfer?", implying that the person does not have shell access to the remote machine.

Answer (score 18):

I made a bash script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
ftp_site=ftp.yoursite.net
username=my_user_name
passwd=my_password
remote=/path/to/remote/folder
folder=$1
cd /path/to/local/folder/$folder
pwd
ftp -in <<EOF
open $ftp_site
user $username $passwd
mkdir $remote/$folder
cd $remote/$folder
mput *
close
bye
```

and called it with

```bash
find . -type d -exec ./recursive-ftp.sh {} \;
```

seems to work.

Answer (score 11):

This is not possible with the normal ftp program as mput does not use recursion. You could use ncftp and then call 'mput -r folder'.

Best wishes,
Fabian

Comment: That's exactly what I did recently on an RHEL 5 box. In the EPEL package, the executable is named ncftpput.

Comment: Can't change anything in the server's configuration. I'm just an user...

Comment: It depends on your client. Not on the server.

Comment: I prefer to do it this way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

open powershell
cd to the directory you want to upload
run the following commands:

```
1. gci -r | % {if ($_.PSIsContainer) {$t = $((($_.fullname -split "\\")[$(((pwd) -split "\\").length)..200]) -join "/"); "mkdir ""$t""`r`nmput ""$t/*"" ""$t"""}} | sc .\mput_all
2. notepad .\mput_all
```

Paste the results into your ftp window. Enjoy. Also don't forget to add mput * to transfer all the files from the base directory.

Comment: Since when does PowerShell run on a Unix system?

Answer (score 0):

Secure Copy   scp  has a -r recursive flag that you might find useful.

Comment: Question is about simple ftp access.. not scp/sftp!